# Confirming or Dismissing Dialog when using Puppeteer

Tags: php, puppeteer

I'm trying to dismiss a dialog within Puppeteer. I tried to convert original Puppeteer instructions, but did not work.

The website I'm crawling throws up the alert from within `body onload`.

Here is what I have so far with no luck.

```
$js_function = JsFunction::createWithAsync()
     ->body('async dialog => {
     await dialog.dismiss();
}');

$this->page->on('dialog', $js_function);

$this->page->goto($this->url);
```

Original puppeteer docs:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-dialog

Comment: From your code I see you are using puphpeteer rather than the Puppeteer. In Puppeteer I could get it to work but perhaps due to the missing asynchronous event handling in PHP the implementation just does not support properly handling dialogs. There is also an [unanswered issue in the project's tracker](https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer/issues/92) so this might be an indicator it is just not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did almost everything right, but there is one small bug.

Here correct code:

```
$js_function = JsFunction::createWithAsync()
    ->parameters(['dialog'])
    ->body('await dialog.dismiss();');

$this->page->on('dialog', $js_function);

$this->page->goto($this->url);
```

And here example of code, if you wanna confirm:

```
$js_function = JsFunction::createWithAsync()
    ->parameters(['dialog'])
    ->body('await dialog.accept();');

$this->page->on('dialog', $js_function);

$this->page->goto($this->url);
```